# Using ARCore and IMU sensors to generate world movement and location data

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, arcore, imu

I am trying to work on an Android application that reads sensor data from the phone, and generates world location to a spreadsheet every specific interval.

I have read about using double-integration on Linear Acceleration, but I've read a lot of articles and papers that say it is inefficient and inaccurate, and it won't provide me with the actual world location data. However, I am seeing applications like **Just A Line** for example that accurately reads the world location of the mobile phone.

So my question is, is there an easy method (whether using ARCore or not) to actually read that world location data and store it in a spreadsheet or something?

Thanks!